# indexOf on array of object instead of array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know to find a value exist or not in an array I can use indexOf, but how to do it with an array of object?

```
const x = [{
  "id": "roadshows",
  "name": "Roadshows"
}, {
  "id": "sporting_events",
  "name": "Sporting Events"
}]

console.log( x.indexOf('roadshows') ) // don't work
```

Comment: obvously indexOf works only for primitive type values. You gotta loop through array

Comment: There's no built-in function that does this. You could do it using libraries like underscore.js or lodash. Otherwise you have to write your own loop.

Comment: `x.map(o => o.id).indexOf('roadshows')`

Comment: `x.findIndex(o => o.id === 'roadshows')`

Answer (score 7):

Since this is tagged [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6), here's an ES6 array method: [`Array#findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
const x = [{
  "id": "roadshows",
  "name": "Roadshows"
}, {
  "id": "sporting_events",
  "name": "Sporting Events"
}]

console.log( x.findIndex( o => o.id === 'roadshows' ) )
```

If you want a more re-useable way of doing this, consider creating a factory `isId(id)`:

```js
function isId(id) {
  return (o) => o.id === id;
}

const x = [{
  "id": "roadshows",
  "name": "Roadshows"
}, {
  "id": "sporting_events",
  "name": "Sporting Events"
}]

console.log( x.findIndex( isId('roadshows') ) )
```

This is referred to as a "factory" because it is a function that returns a function with the passed parameter in its scope.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through since you have  object's inside array.

```
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].id== 'roadshows') {
        console.log(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Or if you just checking that the object exist with that id, filter is handy

```
if (x.filter(function(e) x.id== 'roadshows').length > 0) {
  // Yay. Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

manually I'd do something like this:

```
for(let item of x) {
 if ( item.hasOwnProperty('id') && item['id'] == 'roadshows' ) {   
    //do your stuff here
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

First and foremost, [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). You pass it a function that tests if an element is what you are looking for, it returns the index of the first element that makes that function return `true`.

```
x.findIndex((o) => o.id === 'roadshows');
```

```js
const x = [{
  "id": "roadshows",
  "name": "Roadshows"
}, {
  "id": "sporting_events",
  "name": "Sporting Events"
}];

console.log(x.findIndex((o) => o.id === 'roadshows'));
```

Another option is first [mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the relevant property to an array and [searching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) in that one.

```
x.map((o) => o.id).indexOf('roadshows');
```

```js
const x = [{
  "id": "roadshows",
  "name": "Roadshows"
}, {
  "id": "sporting_events",
  "name": "Sporting Events"
}];

console.log(x.map((o) => o.id).indexOf('roadshows'));
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you can use es6 and want to return the object in question, then there is always `Array.prototype.find()`

```
x.find( item => { return item.id === "roadshows" } )

// returns {id: "roadshows", name: "Roadshows"}
```